# Any direct experimental proof of the invariance of light speed to observers?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, observers

SR was based on the postulate that the light speed is constant and independent of both the motions of source and observer.
There are many experiments proving the constant light speed independent of the motion of source.
Is there any direct experimental proof of the invariance of light speed with respect to moving observers? Direct means that it was not inferred by equivalence, because equivalence itself was not directly proven by experiement.

If not, what is the difficulty?

Comment: Why do you think the [Michelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) proved that the speed of light is independent of the speed of the source and not that it is invariant w.r.t. the speed of the observer?

Comment: Moreover, the speed of a wave being independent of the speed of its source is nothing specific to light and has nothing to do with special relativity. The speed of a sound-wave is also independent of the speed of the source; this is a generic aspect of the wave phenomenon.

Comment: Michelson-Morley experiment proved that the difference of light speed in different direction, if any, is much lower than the earth speed, which invalidate the prediction of ether theory. It never proved that the light speed is constant regardless of the direction.

Comment: Just as I said, the light speed independent of the speed of its source is well established. But not that it is independent of the observer. Just as you mentioned, a sound wave speed is independant of the source, but it depends on the observer. Think an observer in a supersonic airplane.

Comment: Every experiment is precise only to a certain degree. Is your question about the precision of the extent to which we know the speed of light is invariant [w.r.t. the observer]?

Comment: No. I believe the invariance of light speed is well proven regarding to moving source. I can name so many experiments supporting the conclusion. But why not one proving the invariance as to a moving observer?

Comment: I meant invariance of speed w.r.t. the observer. And you just read one, the MM experiment, I am not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: The invariance to moving source was proven with high precision. the uniformity of the 
timing signature of the binary x-ray pulsar system Her X1, the measurement of the speed of gamma rays emitted by fast pions. Why it is not for moving observer?

Comment: See the section titled "Limits on Velocity Variations with Frequency" here https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/experiments.html#cosmological

Comment: And, as you can see here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6080-x , experimental proof of the constancy of the speed of light abounds

Answer (score 2):

An observer is, by definition, at rest in their own frame. So what you are asking for is a test that would detect if an observer were moving relative to an external “absolute” frame, usually called the aether frame. The direct experimental signature of that is anisotropy in the speed of light.

See this list of experimental evidence for SR:
http://www.edu-observatory.org/physics-faq/Relativity/SR/experiments.html

All of the tests for light speed isotropy explicitly and directly test your question. Furthermore, all of the tests of Lorentz invariance indirectly test your question. Also, tests of the principle of relativity imply that the tests with moving sources are also valid tests of moving observers. Finally, any test of the relativistic Doppler effect shows the symmetry of observers and sources for light and several of those use moving absorbers.

Comment: Why not a direct experiment? Just as those already done with moving the light source.

Comment: The isotropy experiments are direct experiments. An observer cannot move relative to itself. So asking about a moving observer implies movement relative to an absolute frame. The direct experimental signature of that is anisotropy.

Comment: Thanks. Let me double check. I thought they are related to the source.