# Deriving time dilation from a moving photon clock

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

This is my attempt of simple derivation of time dilation from a moving photon clock.
Consider this schematics:

[image]

A) is photon clock as seen from a photon clock reference frame (or
as by observer outside when photon clock would be stationary)

B) is when photon clock moves, and is seen by observer outside of photon clock reference frame.

According to A) in one clock tick (1 period) photon moves distance $2L$ (height of clock), so photon speed is :

$$ c=\frac {2L}{T_1} \tag {1},$$
where $T_1$ is tick duration in photon clock reference frame.

According to B) photon travels per 1 tick distance $2x$, so by outside observer photon speed is :
$$ c= \frac {2x}{T_2}, \tag {2}$$
Where $T_2$ is time duration of 1 tick as is seen from outside reference frame.

Now because light speed is the same in all reference frames, we can equate :

$$ \frac {2L}{T_1} = \frac {2x}{T_2} \tag 3 $$

According to Pythagoras theorem,
$$ x= \sqrt{L^2+l^2} \tag 4 $$

Substituting (4) into (3), and expressing tick duration ratios, we get :

$$ \frac {T_2}{T_1} = \frac {\sqrt{L^2+l^2}}{L}  \tag 5$$

Multiplying in RHS numerator and denominator by $1/L$ we get :

$$ \frac {T_2}{T_1} = \sqrt {1 + \frac {l^2}{L^2}} \tag 6$$

Acknowledging that $l$ is distance traveled of photon clock moving forward with speed $v$ per half of proper tick $T_1/2$, and similarly - $L$ is distance traveled by photon in own reference frame per same half of proper tick. So we can re-write (6) into :

$$ \frac {T_2}{T_1} = \sqrt {1 + \frac {(v~T_1/2)^2}{(c~T_1/2)^2}} \tag 7 $$

After simplification (7) becomes,

$$ \frac {T_2}{T_1} = \sqrt {1 + \frac {v^2}{c^2}} \tag 8 $$

What I've got is "something a bit like" a Lorentz factor. From the wiki is seems that there's an [alternative forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) of Lorentz factor like :
$$ \gamma ={\sqrt {1+\left({\frac {p}{m_{0}c}}\right)^{2}}} \tag 9,$$

but I'm not sure if equation (8) can be reduced to (9) or vise-versa. So it's more probably that I've made an error somewhere in derivation or in concepts/ schematics.

Question is,- Does (8) equation valid and if not - Where I have made an error and How to derive correct Lorentz factor for time dilation from a moving photon clock ?

Comment: If you assume that speed of light is constant then this time dilation obtained. But what decide path or length $x$. It is decided by distance by light in rest frame $L$  and distance by frame or clock $l$. So how in relativity or geometry, two perpendicular made a triangle and length of hypotenuse is equal to one arm. If stream is flowing at speed $v$ and swimmer has speed $c$ in still water. Now swimmer crosses flowimg stream  what is speed of swimmer with bank of stream. Do you say time is different unless you persist that speed of swimmer is constant.

Comment: Example with swimmer is incorrect, because swimmer is dragged by river flow, while light is not dragged forward neither by moving light source, not by some ether (such ether existence is disproved). And light speed constancy is proven. So yes, if light speed is the same in all moving inertial reference frames, then time flow rate must change.

Comment: Then how you assume that light take path $x$ when clock is moving. If light is not dragged, then it takes path $L$, without considering speed of clock, one can't assume path is $x$. In booster factor, one already calculated that speed. This is similar to swimmer and result is same if groundman assume that speed of swimmer is same, but time measure by swimmer is slow.

Comment: Path taken depends on observer, in own clock reference frame it's $L$ as you noted, but in external observers view- it's $x$,- hypotenuse of right triangle due to spaceship movement. In other words, it's a relative movement, not dragging. While river changes relative to the ground swimmer speed,- thus it really drags the swimmer. Light does not change it's speed in any external observer view, thus it's not dragged. You seem to completely ignore this important difference.

Comment: So in your triangle, speed of hypotenuse is $c$, speed of perpendicular is $c$, now you says it's $\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$. That means whatever it speed, it is relative, either in hypotenuse or perpendicular. Still you are not answering that how path of $x$ came. Is it same for different speed of clock, no. It means  $x$ depends upon relative speed of photon and clock. Also, sum of square of right angleside gives hypotenuse, not the otherway, only variable is clock speed and result in relative speed of light.

Comment: _now you says it's $\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$_ No, no no, I don't say that,- you seems like very much argumentation error "straw man", i.e. you attack the ideas which I have never said. Where do you get this nonsense conclusion? But yes, light speed along hypotenuse $x$ and along $L$ is the same and equals $c$. Again, NO- **light** speed is NOT relative, but absolute, everywhere is $c$, doesn't matter from where you'll test it. Speed of objects with **rest mass** IS relative to each other, right. BUT this does not apply to _mass-less_ particles like photon and others who already travel at $c$.

Comment: Because that triangle form of relative motion, first accept that whether light or swimmer same triangle form but they never said speed in both length is same. Ration of length must equal to ratio of speed and fix the speed of $L$ first.

Comment: Again, your mistake is that you apply relative motion to an electromagnetic wave. You can't do that, light (and all EM waves) travels at $c$, despite from where and how you'll catch photons. If you will measure light speed along $l$ direction, it's speed would be same: $c$ ! Don't argue with facts. Your logic will not work here, better check [relativity postulates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postulates_of_special_relativity): _the speed of light in free space has the same value c in **all inertial frames of reference**_

Comment: You can travel with a spaceship to an Alpha Centauri star system at $0.5c$ speed and fire a laser beam from a ship to Centauri system, but still Centauri "beings" will catch your beam traveling at $c$, not at $1.5c$ ! And not even slightly $\gt c$. No. Beam speed relative to Alpha Centauri will be same - $c$ (only due to your ship kinetic energy added to a photon, light caught by Centaurians will be blue-shifted,- relativistic Doppler effect). Seems you miss some crucial knowledge from relativity theory. So better go study it without making false claims due to not knowing something.

Comment: Where I used wave, when talking about motion and using algebraic geomtry, things valid for all. What you are doing is the same thing from inception, that using triangle of relativity and denyimg that basis of this triangle is different speed in different frame. The ratio of distance depends upon speed, $\frac{x}{L}=\frac{c^2+v^2}{c}$, now time dilation is only possible when we take this ratio of length but insisting on same speed, $\frac{T_2}{T_1}=\frac{x/c}{L/c}$.

Comment: "_denying that basis of this triangle is different speed in different frame_", No i'm not. It's scientific fact that doesn't matter the path- light travels always at $c$. have you read relativity postulates ? Seems you have not, hence you are not interested in true science, but only in your crazy thoughts. _when we take this ratio of length but insisting on same speed_ Again, we are not insisting, it's the fact that light speed is the same in all frames,- [experimental proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616096/205969). I don't have what else to say to you if you deny scientific facts.

Comment: Don't say things on name of fact, theories change in the past and may be in future. If light's speed is same then why it choses path of relative speed as similar as swimmer. What it's purpose to have extra time for fun. If you reduce relative speed to zero, still it travels on same path. No, that's what I am saying that path is dependent on speed of frame. Now what determine that on going on relative path, light still have same speed, exclusive for light. If light is independent of relative speed, it choses same path and have same time. Read above comments, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I see is in (7), you put in $T_1$ when it should be $T_2$, because

$$v=2l/T_2$$

Your equation (7) should be

$$\frac {T_2}{T_1} = \sqrt {1 + \frac {(v~T_2/2)^2}{(c~T_1/2)^2}} $$

If you then solve for $$T_2/T_1$$ you should get the correct Lorentz factor.

Comment: Also, I did not know you could use ~ as a space character, so that's a fun fact

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid error I've made. Indeed if we take speed and ship traveled length $l$ which external observer sees, then we should take tick period $T_2$ as is seen by same external observer. Good catch ! Btw, $v=2l/T_2$, because $T_2$ is full round-trip, but that's just a minor fix.

Comment: Yes, I thought one thing and typed another

Answer (score 0):

Lorentz Factor was long before using it by Einstein there for other proposes.

there are 2 questionable approaches to deriving Lorentz transformation from 1905 and 1916 by Einstein

following I'd show a better and more comprehensible approach.
If we assume t′
and x′
as linear functions of t
and x
, we can write:
t'=at+bx,(1)
x'=ct+dx.(2)
or
Δt'=aΔt+bΔx,(3)
and
Δx'=cΔt+dΔx.(4)
from (2) if x′=0
, x=−ct/d
, so −c/d=v
, and if x=0
, x′=ct
, and from (1) t′=at
, so x′=ct′/a
, and c/a=−v
, so from the definition of relative velocity we get d=a
,and c=−av
,
x′=ax−avt(6)
t′=at+bx(5)
and now if two snapshots from 1-meter-rods in two inertial system are equal, so from (6) at t=0
if x′=1x=1/a
and from (5) at (t′=0
if x=1
), at=−b
and from (6) x′=a+bv
and acc. to the relativity x=x′
, this results b=(1/a−a)/v
, and we get the general transformation equations without gamma.
x′=a(x−vt)(7)
t′=at−[(a−1/a)/v]x(8)
If a=1
you get Galileo Transformation, and if x=ct
, x′=ct′
then you get the LT. but time dilation and length contraction can be found in general form too, and these are not specific properties of STR.

Atomic clocks example is an obvious trick. In 1905 in "On the Electrodynamic of Moving Bodies" Einstein doesn't speak of the real slowing of clocks in the moving system. He has said only if the time definition was correct, then the time at the moving system would be shorter than the observer's, seen from the observer's point of view.